# Pentaho Spoon Transformation - Errors

Tags: sql, transformation, pentaho-spoon

I have been trying to run a transformation where I have Table Input with SQL to fetch or query data, tied to output for an excel spreadsheet.

With the following SQL I get multiple errors depending on what I add or take away. I am connected to Oracle databases.

```
SELECT FROM .View 

WHERE ((View.Opened_Date 

BETWEEN ' 2016-01-01' 

AND ' 2017-01-01' 

AND View.Owner_Group='OwnerJ' 

AND View.Main_Category1 LIKE '%BUCKETS%'))
```

I get the following error when trying to preview:

```
Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
```

Goes on to say its killed all other steps. No long that I can find. Earlier when I ran the SQL I got date errors. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be selecting any columns from the table.
There are leading spaces in the dates and you should apply TO_DATE to the dates that are in string format.
There are unnecessary parentheses that could be removed.
Also, I think that '.View' should be just 'View'.

```
SELECT column1Name, column2Name, ... FROM View 

WHERE View.Opened_Date 

BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 

AND TO_DATE('2017-01-01' , 'yyyy-mm-dd')

AND View.Owner_Group='OwnerJ' 

AND View.Main_Category1 LIKE '%BUCKETS%'
```